# How to make (only) the main path virtual in the diamond problem

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

This code does not compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class BaseV1 {
public:
    BaseV1(int i = 0) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    void foo() {}
};

class DataV1 : public BaseV1 {
public:
    DataV1() : BaseV1(1) {}
};


class BaseV2 : public BaseV1 {};

class DataV2 : public DataV1, public BaseV2 {};


int main() {
    DataV2().foo(); // request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

So I read about the diamond problem, and I came up with what I thought is this solution, which makes one complete path (`DataV2 : BaseV2 : BaseV1`) virtual. However, that does not change anything;

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class BaseV1 {
public:
    BaseV1(int i = 0) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    void foo() {}
};

class DataV1 : public BaseV1 {
public:
    DataV1() : BaseV1(1) {}
};


class BaseV2 : virtual public BaseV1 {};

class DataV2 : public DataV1, virtual public BaseV2 {};


int main() {
    DataV2().foo(); // request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

I made the example compile by making the other path (`DataV2 : DataV1 : BaseV1`) virtual, which is not really what I want, because I do not like touching the existing code base (`V1`) too much:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class BaseV1 {
public:
    BaseV1(int i = 0) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    void foo() {}
};

class DataV1 : virtual public BaseV1 { // I do not want to make this virtual, I think.
public:
    DataV1() : BaseV1(1) {}
};


class BaseV2 : virtual public BaseV1 {};

class DataV2 : virtual public DataV1, public BaseV2 {
public:
    DataV2() : DataV1() {}
};


int main() {
    DataV1().foo(); // this prints 1, as expected
    DataV2().foo(); // this prints 0, not 1 - so DataV1's constructor is skipped
    return 0;
}
```

And even though the code does compile, it is failing at runtime as `DataV1`'s constructor seems to be skipped.

So, my question is: how can I avoid the diamond problem here, ideally without touching the `V1` inheritance path?

Comment: *"as DataV1's constructor seems to be skipped."*, with virtual inheritance, it is to the most derived class to construct the virtual bases.

Comment: @Jarod42 that is true. However, I would have thought that `DataV2() : DataV1() {}` would take care of that...

Comment: `DataV2() : DataV1() {}` is in fact `DataV2() : BaseV1(), DataV1(), BaseV2() {}`.

Comment: Are you really sure that you need diamond inheritance most of the times it is a sign you want code reuse and try to solve it with inheritance (note even with OO inheritance is rarely the best solution). If you need multiple inheritance inherit then inherit from multiple abstract base classes and use crtp/mixin to aggregate implementations (reuse of code) or just use plain aggregation and forward (typing the least amount of code should never be your main design choice)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I feared I would get your comment. Which is another sign that diamond inheritance is not the best way to got here :) Rest assured that I have opted out of this solution, also because SonarQube warns of virtual inheritance in general, so no one else will actually like my solution :)

Comment: Why fear? Sounds like you already had doubts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtual` doesn't magically solve all problems. `virtual` inheritance of `BaseV1` makes it so that the most-derived class directly inherits from `BaseV1`. But that means that `DataV2` still has two `BaseV1` classes - one it inherits from directly, and one inside `DataV1`.

Possible solutions:

- Make `DataV1` also have virtual inheritance (obviously)
- Have `DataV2` to simply not inherit from `DataV1`.
- Keep everything as-is and give `DataV2` its own `void foo()` method that delegates to a specific inner implementation (ex: `void foo() {DataV1::foo();}`)